# SwiftUI - How to get notified when dragging and releasing on an view

Tags: swiftui

I have two circles on my screen (top and bottom). I want the user to press down on the top circle, and drag to the bottom one.

I'm not dragging and dropping (I don't want the UI to change).

I just want to know that the user started on the top one, and released their finger on the bottom circle. When the user releases their finger on the bottom one.

I haven't been able to find my answer from other questions.

### Current code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .named("mySpace"))
                        .onChanged { value in
                            
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            // if value.location == endPoint { 
                            //    print("user started press on blue and ended on green")
                            // }
                        }
                )

            Spacer()
            
            Circle()
                .fill()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }.coordinateSpace(name: "mySpace")
    }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image: Example of UI]

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to reach, maybe you could add more info or gif about what you are trying.

Comment: Than you @swiftPunk , I have updated my question to be more clear I hope!

Comment: So I think the right way for asking would be: You want get notified, if Circle Blue dragged and released on green one right? otherwise you would not like get notification about it

Comment: Thank you. Sorry my explanation was not very good. I agree and have updated the title to reflect

Comment: there is no build it functionality that Shapes or objects be aware of itself or others that they are in same place, we should make it in custom way, is that you want?

Comment: I see. Yeah I believe that’s what I want. Any approach to be able to solve this. I don’t necessarily need code, but direction. Although code would be nice too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I could find a way for get notified wether this 2 Circles are in some part inside each other:

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    typealias OffsetType = (offset: CGSize, lastOffset: CGSize)
    
    @State private var objects: [OffsetType] = [(offset: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -200.0), lastOffset: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -200.0)),
                                                (offset: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 200.0), lastOffset: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 200.0))]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            CircleView(color: Color.blue)
                .offset(objects[0].offset)
                .gesture(dragGesture(indexOfObject: 0))
            
            CircleView(color: Color.green)
                .offset(objects[1].offset)
                .gesture(dragGesture(indexOfObject: 1))
            
        }
        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.1))
        
    }
    
    func dragGesture(indexOfObject: Int) -> some Gesture {
        
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged() { value in
                
                objects[indexOfObject].offset = CGSize(width: objects[indexOfObject].lastOffset.width + value.translation.width,
                                                       height: objects[indexOfObject].lastOffset.height + value.translation.height)
                
                
            }
            .onEnded() { value in
                
                objects[indexOfObject].lastOffset = CGSize(width: objects[indexOfObject].lastOffset.width + value.translation.width,
                                                           height: objects[indexOfObject].lastOffset.height + value.translation.height)
                
                objects[indexOfObject].offset = objects[indexOfObject].lastOffset
                
                distance()
                
            }
        
    }
    
    func distance() {
        
        if pow(pow((objects[1].offset.width - objects[0].offset.width), 2.0) + pow((objects[1].offset.height - objects[0].offset.height), 2.0), 0.5) <= 100 { print("same place!") }
    }
    
}
```

---

```
struct CircleView: View {
    
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Circle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @swiftPunk, thank's for answering the question, really appreciated. I understand the approach and it works works well!